# How to make GCC output to stdout?

Tags: c, gcc

GCC is normally instructed to output to a file via the `-o` switch. If this isn't provided it seems to decide on an appropriate name and output to that. How do I make GCC write its generated output to stdout?

Comment: Where are you going to pipe it to?

Comment: As ergosys's answer implies, some invocations of GCC will output an assembly file, not binary.  In my case I want to look at it!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
gcc -o /dev/stdout foo.c
```

Note that `/dev/stdout` is defined as a symlink: `/dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1`.

Comment: Now, is there a similar solution for Windows?  Or will I have to hack it for cross-platform solutions?

Comment: @Kevin, wild guess, try `-o CON`? It's been a while since I've done Windows. :/

Comment: **A word of caution on Cygwin**: `gcc -o /dev/stdout foo.c` outputs nothing, but `gcc -c -o /dev/stdout foo.c` **deletes `/dev/stdout`!**

Comment: @Matt So how to make GCC output to stdout on Cygwin?

Comment: I get an illegal seek: `g++ -o /dev/stdout script.cpp` -> `/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Illegal seek`

Comment: @alfC oh, bummer. It looks like this feature has gone away. My gross little `-o/dev/stdout` works fine with ld 2.34 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but fails with ld 2.38 in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. It might be possible to use `-Wl,<something>` to ask ld to work with pipes, but I can't quickly see any options that would work. Probably they were able to make some improvements by giving up single-pass processing.

Answer (score 27):

You can use -o-,  for example to print an assembly listing:

```
gcc -S -o- in.c
```

Comment: It's important to note that this only works for some outputs.  For example `gcc -o- test.c` creates an executable called `-`.

Comment: Its good to understand `-o-` as actually `-o -`. `-` refers to standard input/output depending on the context.

Answer (score -2):

Um, what are you going to do with a binary object file dumped to stdout? anyway, some programs accept the '-' (single minus, no quotes) character as replacement for stdout. If you're on linux, you can do `-o /dev/fd/1`

Comment: Is it safe to just write anything to `/dev/fd/1`?

Comment: @MasBagol Yes, it is.