# How do I get current file path in c++?

Tags: c++

I want get current file path,like in a.cpp,I can get

/home/workspace/src/a.cpp

How can I get this　path?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the standard macro `__FILE__` to which expands to a string literal that contains the path of the current source file.

Starting from C++20, you can use default constructed `std::source_location`.

Comment: This is what I want!

Comment: One more thing,if I want get /home/workspace,how should I use __FILE__？

Comment: I don't think there is any requirement that `__FILE__` contain a path?

Comment: @M.M To be exact *"The presumed name of the current source file"*. There's some discussion about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548263/2079303). As far as I understand, implementation is quite free to provide anything it considers to be name of (what it considers to be) the file. In practice, compilers that I've used include a path in the name.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't comment due to the reputation requirement.

But you might find this useful, a way to retrieve directory on Linux & Windows.

- [How do I get the directory that a program is running from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from)

Hope this help!

Comment: the OP wants the path to the cpp file, not the path to the exe file

Comment: My bad, misread the question! Glad OP found his answer. Apologies!